# YTD, PY YTD values are displaying the same data?

Tags: ssas

I have created the YTD calculation based on the below link:
"http://saldeloera.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/ssas-how-to-create-dynamic-time-calculations-to-reuse-over-any-measure/?blogsub=confirming#blog_subscription-2"

The below is the result set which i can see it in excel:

```
Row Labels  Total Bottles - WeeklyTEB   Weekly-NEW QTY
CurrentMonth        3606357.755         1978514117
CurrentYear         3606357.755         1978514117
PYYTD               3606357.755         1978514117
SelectedDate        3606357.755         1978514117
YTD                 3606357.755         1978514117
Unknown             3606357.755         1978514117
Grand Total         3606357.755         1978514117
```

Values are repeating for the measures. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Noted in the Remarks section, the [YTD function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146039.aspx) will only work for Calendar Years.

I would suggest using the [PeriodsToDate function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144925.aspx).

So if you want a Fiscal YTD:

```
SUM(  PeriodsToDate   (   [Date].[Fiscal YQMD].[Fiscal Year]
                          ,[Date].[Fiscal YQMD].CurrentMember
                      )
      ,[Measures].[Revenue]
   )
```

And shouldn't your measure `[Measures].YEARTODATE` be the measure you are trying to aggregate?  I am guessing a field like `[Measures].[Revenue]`?